# ¿Como eliminar un objeto llamando a una funcion con addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, poo, eventos

Quiro eliminar un objeto del array buscandolo con una funcion en la que autocompleta y muestra los objetos que coinciden con unos botones, y al pulsar el boton llamaria a la funcion que me mostraria un `confirm` que al aceptar llamaría a la funcion del socio `deleteSocio()` la cual deberia borrar el objeto, pero no consigo ni que al pulsar el boton llame al la funcion que contiene el `confirm` ni que la funcion `deleteSocio()` borre un objeto.

os dejo el codigo a ver si me podeis ayudar a ver el error.

```js
function Socio(numero, nombre, apellido1, apellido2, dni, fecNacimiento, localidad, password) {
  this.datos = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];

  this.numero = function() {
    return (100 + arraySocios.length);
  };

  this.valor = function(idx) {
    return this.datos[idx];
  }

  this.socio = function(numero, nombre, apellido1, apellido2, dni, fecNacimiento, localidad, password) {
    this.datos = [numero, nombre, apellido1, apellido2, dni, fecNacimiento, localidad, password];
  };

  this.socio(numero, nombre, apellido1, apellido2, dni, fecNacimiento, localidad, password);

  //Elimina el socio cuyo dni coincide con el que se pasa como parametro.
 this.deleteSocio = function (dni) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.arraySocios.length; i++) {
        if (this.arraySocios[i].datos[4] === dni) {
            this.arraySocios.splice(i, 1);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
}

var nombre, apellido1, apellido2, dni, fecNacimiento, localidad, password, numero;
var socio = new Socio(numero, nombre, apellido1, apellido2, dni, fecNacimiento, localidad, password);

var socio1 = new Socio('100', 'fran', 'martinez', 'piñeiro', '3533994x', '12/02/88', 'caceres', '123');
var socio2 = new Socio('101', 'pablo', 'sampedaro', 'piña', '8839402e', '12/02/88', 'malaga', '123');
var socio3 = new Socio('102', 'esteban', 'martin', 'alonso', '0299313e', '12/02/88', 'sevilla', '123');
var socio4 = new Socio('103', 'eugenio', 'vidal', 'vilar', '3500123e', '12/02/88', 'bilbao', '123');
var arraySocios = [
  socio1,
  socio2,
  socio3,
  socio4
];

   

//eliminar socio
function baja() {

 var mensaje;
var opcion = confirm("Esta seguro que quiere dar de baja el socio "+document.getElementById('dniSocio').value+" ?");
if (opcion === true) {
 socio.deleteSocio(document.getElementById('dniSocio').value);
    mensaje = alert("Socio dado de baja correctamente");
} else {
    mensaje = alert ("Cancelada la baja del socio");
}
}

   function autocompletado() {
  document.getElementById('cuerpo').innerHTML = '<div id="buscador">' +
'<div>' +
'<ul id="demo"></ul>' +
'</div>' +
'</div>';

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '';

  var pal = document.getElementById("buscar-pal").value;

  var tam = pal.length;
  for (indice in arraySocios) {
var item = arraySocios[indice];
var nombre = item.datos[1];
var dni = item.datos[4];
if (pal.length != 0 && dni.length != 0) {
  if (dni.search(pal) != -1) {
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    node.innerHTML = "<a href=" + dni + " id='coincidencia'>Nombre: " + nombre + "</a>" + ' Dni: ' +
      '<input type="text" name="socio" id="dniSocio" value="' + dni + '" readonly>' +
      "<input type='submit' name='borrar' value='Borrar' id='borrar'><input type='submit' name='modificar' value='Modificar' id='modificar'>"; //conseguir que al pulsar elimine objeto.
    document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(node);
    node.addEventListener('click', baja);
  }
}
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <header>

  </header>
  <div class="todo">
    <aside id="asleft"></aside>
    <div id="buscador">
      <h2>Buscar socio</h2>
      <input type="text" id="buscar-pal" onkeyup="autocompletado()" style="border: solid 2px">
    </div>
    <section id="cuerpo"> </section>


    <aside id="asright">

    </aside>
  </div>





</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En cuanto a lo de que no llama a la función de borrar, me imagino que la consola este dándote un error del estilo "can't use addEventListener method of undefined" ya que estás asignando un evento a un objeto que todavía no has creado.

```
function iniciar() {
  document.getElementById("borrar").addEventListener('click', baja);
}
```

La solución más rápida sería esta:

```
function autocompletado() {
  document.getElementById('cuerpo').innerHTML = '<div id="buscador">' +
    '<div>' +
    '<ul id="demo"></ul>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '';

  var pal = document.getElementById("buscar-pal").value;

  var tam = pal.length;
  for (indice in arraySocios) {
    var item = arraySocios[indice];
    var nombre = item.datos[1];
    var dni = item.datos[4];
    if (pal.length != 0 && dni.length != 0) {
      if (dni.search(pal) != -1) {
        var node = document.createElement("li");
        node.innerHTML = "<a href=" + dni + " id='coincidencia'>Nombre: " + nombre + "</a>" + ' Dni: ' +
          '<input type="text" name="socio" id="dniSocio" value="' + dni + '" readonly>' +
          "<input type='submit' name='borrar' value='Borrar' id='borrar'><input type='submit' name='modificar' value='Modificar' id='modificar'>"; //conseguir que al pulsar elimine objeto.
        document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(node);
        node.addEventListener('click', baja);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

He añadido `node.addEventListener('click', baja);` donde creas el `li`, ya que ahora si tienes un elemento donde asignar el evento.

En la función borrar, ya que vas a eliminar el objeto, haz lo siguiente para librar memoria:

```
  this.deleteSocio = function(dni, arraySocios) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arraySocios.length; i++) {
      if (arraySocios[i].dni === dni) {
        delete arraySocios[i];
        arraySocios.splice(i, 1);
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  };
```

Comment: e editado la pregunta y con tu codigo me funciona la llamada a la funcion, pero lo de eliminar objeto no se porque me da un error, como que no reconoce el `length` del `for` de `deleteSocio` y no entiendo el porque

Comment: Claro, el arraySocios no pertenece al objeto/clase, por tanto no sabe que es. He editado la respuesta con un cambio, aunque en si, no es lo ideal, puedes pasarle el array de socios y que lo borre. `socio.deleteSocio(document.getElementById('dniSocio').value, arraySocios);`

Comment: gracias, mea has ayudado con un bloqueo de unas cuantas horas xd